# Razor encodes quoted html attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'd like to conditionally render appropriate HTML to the client using this construct:

```
<input type="button" value="Foo" @(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Identifier) ? string.Format("title={0} disabled=disabled", "Lorem ipsum") : "onclick=window.open('http://www.google.com'); return false;") />
```

This is the output I get:

```
<input type="button" value="Foo" title=&quot;Lorem ipsum&quot; disabled=disabled />
```

I've tried numerous Html.Raw() constructs, but nothing seems to be of any help. How do I output correctly unencoded HTML with quotes instead of html entities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. Just tried it and it worked for me. The difference is the singular quotations marks and the Html.Raw around the whole thing

```
<input type="button" value="Foo" @Html.Raw(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Identifier) ? string.Format("title='{0}' disabled='disabled'", "Lorem ipsum") : "onclick='window.open(\"http://www.google.com\"); return false;'") />
```

Answer (score -2):

I think adding single quotation is enough

```
..."title='{0}' disabled='disabled'"...
```